# I added the Leaflet easybutton but it's not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geodjango

I need to add a button like a home that resets the map. I used the [Leaflet.EasyButton](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton) but It doesn’t show on my map. It doesn’t even show any error in the console.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>
```

Here's my leaflet js file,

```
var lmap = new L.map("lmap", {
  zoomControl: false,
  maxZoom: 11,
  minZoom: 3,
}).setView([34.543896, 63.160652], 6);
L.control.zoom({
  position: 'topright'
}).addTo(lmap);
lmap.addControl(new L.Control.Fullscreen({position: 'bottomleft'}));
L.control.mousePosition({position: 'bottomright', numDigits: 3}).addTo(lmap);
L.control.scalefactor().addTo(lmap);
L.easyButton( 'fa-gbp', function(){
  lmap.setView([55, -2], 4);
}).addTo(lmap);
```

Comment: EasyButton is working correct: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/5wzpjsvg/) Maybe you have a problem with scalefactor or a other library

Comment: yeah but even though I remove other ones it still doesn’t show

Comment: Look into the demo from above, I added the code exactly like you (without other libs) and it works

Comment: I downloaded the files and added them now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked as expected [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/5wzpjsvg/)

The OP downloaded the src files and then it worked.

```
var lmap = new L.map("lmap", {
  zoomControl: false,
  maxZoom: 11,
  minZoom: 3,
}).setView([34.543896, 63.160652], 6);

L.easyButton( 'fa-gbp', function(){
  lmap.setView([55, -2], 4);
}).addTo(lmap)
```